# Count with out using a joins

Tags: sql

I am having issues with my logic. Please help.

The errors I am getting are:
`Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 603
Column 'Client.LastName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 605
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.`

I do not understand how to do an inner sub query with a count function.

> 5. Write a stored procedure called NoJobs that returns the Client first name, last name and PhoneNumber of all the Clients that have not had a job. Do not use a join. (2 marks)

```
Go
Create Procedure NoJobs (@ClientID int = null)
as

If @ClientID is null

Begin 
RaisError ('Must provide Client ID',16,1)
End
Else 
Begin 
Select FirstName,LastName,Phone from Client
group by FirstName,LastName,Phone
having ClientID = (Select Count(*) from Job where Count(*) = 0 group by ClientID)
End
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your query is way off. You are using the having clause to compare ClientID with a count... how do you expect that to work?

What you do want to do is to skip the group by and having clauses and use the `in` operator instead in a condition like:

```
where ClientID not in (select ClientID from job)
```

Comment: thank you so much, i did that logic on otherquestions... i do not know how i missed that it makes so much sense :)